# Claims Based Authentication in SharePoint 2013 Online Not working anymore

Tags: 2013, web-services, sharepoint-online, claims-based-auth, claims

I'm trying to connect an application (desktop application) to SharePoint 2013 sites.

I have a client webservice, the issue is Claims Based Authentication in SharePoint 2013 does not work: http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/t/161102.aspx

Is there another simple way do consume the sharepoint 2013 online webservice without having to connect to the sharepoint site through a browser window.

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to resolve this ?
I also need an answer to this question

Comment: Unfortunately no.
Instead of 'desktop application', I use 'ASP.NET MVC remote web in a Sharepoint Cloud-hosted App', here an example: http://gobbe.net/index.php/2013/06/07/building-an-asp-net-mvc-remote-web-in-a-sharepoint-cloud-hosted-app/